# How to store a large, very frequently accessed list on a server using Django?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, cassandra

So I'm creating a video streaming application using Django. I'm using Cassandra as my database to hold all user content, and video content. Eventually once I'm finished, the app is going to run in the Amazon cloud.

Each video held in the database has about 10 (give or take) columns in it, ranging from large text files to small floats. In my app, I have a function that goes through every video entry in the database and saves each one as a dictionary (matching column names to column values as key names and values), and then creates a large list of all of the dictionaries.

The database is constantly changing (every time any user watches something it changes), so the function has to run every time the page loads in order to have the most up-to-date video files. This is leading to a clear issue, in that if the list becomes very large - say 100,000+ videos - then the program is having to search through and modify 100,000+ items in a list every time the page loads.

My question is, how do I go about having a list of videos on the server that is constantly being updated and retrieved, without having to query the database every time the page loads, or run through the list every time the page loads?

Comment: look to this for ideas: https://killrvideo.github.io/

Comment: While a potentially bigger change that you were thinking of, you might consider using DynamoDB in place of Cassandra and then configure DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX).